# Insert data into multiple tables connected by foreign key PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key

I have two tables which are linked by a foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE clients (
    id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    name character varying,
    phone character varying,
    contact text
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE address (
    id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    line1 character varying,
    city character varying,
    state text,
    zip character varying,
    uuid integer REFERENCES clients(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);
```

My lambda server receives data which should be put into both tables. However the queries I am trying to run are inserting a `NULL` value into the `uuid` foreign key column of my `address` table.

```
BEGIN; 
INSERT INTO clients (name, phone, contact) 
VALUES ('Trevor J','6077730',''); 

INSERT INTO address (line1, city, state, zip) 
VALUES ('82 Haon Street,'Gasto','OH', 51113); 
COMMIT;
```

What am I missing to get the proper foreign key in my table?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only inserting a single row, and there is no other INSERT between the two INSERTs, the easiest way is to use `lastval()` to get the last generated sequence value (which will be the `id` generated for the `clients` table)

```
INSERT INTO clients (name, phone, contact) 
VALUES ('Trevor J','6077730',''); 

INSERT INTO address (line1, city, state, zip, "uuid") 
VALUES ('82 Haon Street','Gasto','OH', 51113, lastval());
```

This is safe for concurrent transactions.

Comment: Could you use a CTE for the first `INSERT` with a `RETURNING` clause and then use that for the second `INSERT`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name would this work if I have a third table which also links to the clients table by a foreign key?  Or will `lastval()` take the id of the address table

Comment: @tdammon: lastval() reflects the value from the **most recently** used sequence. So yes, it would contain the value from the address ID